# Why should threads be created manually if web servers already create them?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some questions in regards to Java threading concepts. I have listed them below.

1. Why do we have to create threads manually? Doesn't the web server create them?
2. Is each request to the web server a thread? If so, how does it handle running them on the same code without colliding with other threads?

Comment: In a web application you generally needn't create threads. Your question is very ambiguous in its current form.

Comment: Java Threading is not just for web apps.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno - So you mean threading is not required in web applications?

Comment: As long as the servlets do not have statically declared variables, each thread will only be touching data belonging to the instance of the servlet in the context of which it is running. Accordingly,  unless you mean to manipulate global data, you do not have to worry about threads "colliding"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do we have to create threads manually? Doesn't the web server create them?

If you're using a web server, and if that server handles threading for you, you don't. For instance, if you're using servlets, you don't create threads; you leave it to the servlet layer. There are many scenarios where you're not running behind something else like that (perhaps you're writing your own web server, or another kind of server; or an app that wants to make use of all the CPU cores in the machine), in which case you may need to handle your own thread creation.

> Is each request to the web server a thread? If so, how does it handle running them on the same code without colliding with other threads?

It depends on the web server you're using. One *typical* approach is to have a pool of threads and to assign requests to those threads. The request uses the thread until the request is complete, perhaps running alongside other requests on other threads, and when the request is satisfied, the thread goes back to the pool to be reused. But that's just one way a web server may be written.

Answer (score 1):

> Is each request to the web server a thread?

The application server handles http traffic by managing an http worker thread pool, and this is transparent to us when we write web applications in java.  This threadpool is limited in size, and, every thread iteratively consumes requests from a queue - having a thread per request could simply kill your machine scheduler.

Just remember that our servlet, or JSP, or any abstraction we use is called by one of these threads, and you must be aware of the implications of each abstraction (for example, look for differences between an Struts 1 Action class and a Spring MVC Controller class).

> Why do we have to create threads manually?

In JEE, you are not actually supposed to create threads, but to rely on whatever mechanism the app server gives you in order to do that.  Some application servers manage dedicated threadpools for you to send heavy tasks to be executed in the background, for example work managers.

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/TASKS/workmanagers.htm

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fasyncbns%2Fconcepts%2Fcasb_workmgr.html